# Find Function Not Working On Second Run of Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2013 and running a macro for a second time after running it once a few seconds before.

On my first run, the macro runs nominally. However, if I try to run it a second time a section of my code (principally the use of range.find) returns nothing when I expect it to find something.

The problematic code:

```
If facilsheet.Cells(d.Row, d.Column + 2).Value <> vbNullString Then
   If facilsheet.Cells(d.Row, d.Column + 2).Value <> "--" Then
       net_event = facilsheet.Cells(d.Row, d.Column + 2).Value
       net_event = CDate(net_event)
       Debug.Print net_event
       Debug.Print "net_event is  a " & TypeName(net_event)
       Debug.Print timelinesheet.Cells(3, 4).Value
       Debug.Print "timelinesheet cell is " & TypeName(timelinesheet.Cells(3, 4).Value)
       Set rng2 = timelinesheet.Range("3:3").Find(what:=net_event, MatchCase:=False)
    End if
End If
```

The first time I run the code (the nominal situation, when everything works), the debug returns:

9/6/2016
net_event is  a String
9/6/2016
the timelinesheet cell is a Date

and rng2 is not Nothing.

The second time I run this, the debug returns the same thing as above but rng2 is Nothing.

I tried explicitly stating all of the parameters for Find to see if that would work.

'timelinesheet' is a public variable. Might this be a public variable issue? There are other places throughout my macro where I use find with 'timelinesheet' and everything works just fine during the second run.

Comment: When you run it the second time, do you get any value for `net_event`?

Comment: Hi Zac, yes, I do. The value is 9/6/2016 (as expected)

Comment: Can you change `timelinesheet.range ...` to `Woksheets("<whatever your sheet name is>").Range ...` and try it

Comment: I attempted    Worksheets("Timeline").Range("3:3
").Find(what:=net_event,MatchCase:=False‌​) but no joy either.

Comment: @kpgeeting can you post the rest of your code (if it's not too long) ?

Comment: what's the rest of your code doing with `rng2`?

Comment: Some conditional formatting occurs if rng2 is not nothing: `If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                                    For Each f In rng2.Cells
                                        With timelinesheet.Cells(c.Row, f.Column)
                                            .Value = "NET" `

Comment: that's not "conditional formatting"... you're writing "NET" in some cells of timelinesheet , i.e. the very same sheet `rng2` belongs to! Check you're not overwriting rng2. BTW rng2 is supposed to be a one cell range so what's the use of looping through its cells?

Comment: It's not 'conditional formatting', no. I meant conditional in the sense of the 'if' statement. My apologies for the loose language. However I'm not overwriting the address of rng2 thereafter. The issue is that rng2 is Nothing right after `Set rng2 = timelinesheet.Range("3:3").Find(what:=net_event, MatchCase:=False)` for the second run, despite the fact that I see there should be a potential date match of 9/6/2016 (net_event's value) to timelinesheet.cells(3,4).Value (a cell on the sheet I know has the same date, 9/6/2016).

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt this is a public variable issue as mentioned in some of the comments.

This works for me:

```
Sub test()

    Dim facilsheet As Excel.Worksheet, timelinesheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim net_event, rng2 As Range

    ' for testing purposes only
    Set facilsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set timelinesheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    net_event = facilsheet.Cells(1, 1).Value

    ' purposely commented out 
    'net_event = CDate(net_event)

    Debug.Print net_event
    Debug.Print "net_event is  a " & TypeName(net_event)
    Debug.Print timelinesheet.Cells(3, 4).Value
    Debug.Print "timelinesheet cell is " & TypeName(timelinesheet.Cells(3, 4).Value)
    Set rng2 = timelinesheet.Rows(3).Find(what:=net_event, MatchCase:=False) ' notice I changed Range to Rows

    Debug.Print "rng2.Address: " & rng2.Address

End Sub
```

I suspect your problem arises because of the conversion to date in the line I've commented out and because the formatting of one/both of the cells in question is changed between executions. I can recreate your problem if I change the formatting of the `net_value` cell between executions of the sub and I do the date conversion of `net_event`, but not if I comment this line of code out.